# How to convert log10 values to decimal

Tags: logarithms

I need to convert $\log_{10}(1.07366)$ to decimal.
Need the equation for the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert log to decimal"? You want a numerical formula for the logarithm?

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: The result is $0.03086677$.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to compute the outcome, you need to find a logarithm table (http://www.sosmath.com/tables/logtable/logtable.html) or a calculator that can calculate logarithms. Most give you the natural logarithm (***ln*** - the base e logarithm). So you need to convert. The way to do it is to use the formula:
$$log_b(a)=\frac{ln(a)}{ln(b)}$$